# Lubuntu screen issues

Tags: mouse, lubuntu, screen

I instantly admit that I am a ubuntu newbie, so this might be the dumbest of questions.  But I am endeavouring to get my kids off Windows and elected to convert one of our laptops (a Gateway W33-UI1) into a dual boot Lubuntu/XP machine.

I downloaded the iso, created the disc and booted the machine from the disc and attempted to run from the disc - rather than commit to the install. All was going swimmingly, until the screen rastered with interference lines across top and bottom and covered the screen in horizontal red stripes.

Lubuntu still loaded, although everything appears transparent over this red stripe interference and the mouse pointer is corrupted so that it is now just a collection of random faint pixels in the rough shape of a large square.

I have refreshed the video drivers, but to no avail.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?
Many thanks in advance for your sage advice.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Which version of (L)ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Driver refreshes aren't going to work on LiveCD.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue with my dad's old gateway laptop trying to install the same thing (Lubuntu 12.10 I'm assuming). Though I remembered 12.04 live booting on it without a hitch, and sure enough I had no problems booting or installing. I suppose installing 12.10 may solve the issue for that version, but I didn't test it.